# Undefined label in java android

Tags: java, android

Help i'm getting an error on '`break label60`' and '`break label54`', it says  `undefined label"`.

Thanks for the response ..

```
        int i=0;
        if (Jeep.getCenterX() <= x)
        {
            i = 1;
            if (150 + Jeep.getCenterX() < x) {
                break label54;
            }
        }
        label54:
        for (int j = 1;; j = 0)
        {
            if (((i & j) == 0) || (Jeep.getCenterY() > y) || (87 + Jeep.getCenterY() < y)) {
                break label60;
            }
            return true;
            i = 0;
            break;
        }
        label60:
        return false;
```

Comment: `i = 0;` after `return true;` :)

Comment: `break label60;` is not needed and is `label54` even inside a loop? Not sure what you are trying to do, but breaking to labels is not the conventional way to program in Java. You can most likely achieve this without labels.

Comment: Somehow developing an appetite for pasta...

Comment: Have you Reverse Engineer any APK file ?

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioning that labeled `break` and `continue` are bad practice, the label should be placed before `switch`, `for`, `while`, or `do-while` statement, not after, so it should be:

```
label60:
for (...) {
    if (...) {
        break label60;
    }
}
```

[See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)